# My answer is fetching multiple rows apart from the rows provided in the output

Tags: oracle, plsql, formatting

I am trying to write a PLSQL block to display details of books along with their Author and Publisher. problem statement is as follow: Use String functions to display only the first 10 letters of column 'Title' and Sort the result set based on 'Title' in ascending order. Schema details are given below:-

Table Name Columns

```
1.author authorid, firstname, lastname

2.book author_id, bookid, publisherid, title

3.publisher publisherid, publishername
```

Output format is as follows:

```
BOOKID.............TITLE.............publisher.............Author

639163050...........10 Years o...........Prentice Hall...........Paul Deitel

330895717...........African Fo...........Prentice Hall...........Tem Nieto
```

---

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
cursor c is

select * from book b 
left join author on authorid=author_id 
left join publisher p on b.publisherid=p.publisherid
order by title asc;

begin 

 dbms_output.put_line('BOOKID'||'.............'||'TITLE'||'.............'||'publisher'||'.............'||'Author');

for i in c loop

dbms_output.put_line(i.bookid||'.............'||substr(i.title,1,10)||'.............'||i.publishername||'.............'||concat(i.firstname||' ',i.lastname));

end loop;

end;
/

OUTPUT is coming as below:-

BOOKID.............TITLE.............publisher.............Author
639163050.............10 Years o.............Prentice Hall.............Paul Deitel
330895717.............African Fo.............Prentice Hall.............Tem Nieto
110125075.............African Fu.............Prentice Hall.............Tem Nieto
162261197.............An Antholo.............Prentice Hall.............Paul Deitel
730284192.............Introducti.............Prentice Hall PTG.............Harvey Deitel
260895501.............Jambula Tr.............Prentice Hall PTG.............Harvey Deitel
120284191.............Land Apart.............Prentice Hall PTG.............Tem Nieto
230856118.............Less Than .............Prentice Hall.............Harvey Deitel
199163050.............Love Child.............Prentice Hall.............Sean Santry
140829293.............Nobody Eve.............Prentice Hall PTG.............Sean Santry
220161438.............Of Suffoca.............Prentice Hall PTG.............Harvey Deitel
130895725.............Op{-truncated-}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you're saying, you'll need `RPAD` (to full column length, counting dots as well), along with `SUBSTR`. Something like this:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    -- Header
  3    dbms_output.put_line(
  4      'BOOKID.............TITLE.............publisher.............Author');
  5
  6    -- You'd actually join those tables to get the result; I'm fabricating it
  7    -- as you didn't post proper sample data
  8    for cur_r in (select 639163050 bookid, '10 years of something' title,
  9                        'Prentice Hall' publisher, 'Paul Dietel' author   from dual union all
 10                  select 330895717       , 'African fog is foggy'       ,
 11                        'Prentice Hall'          , 'Tem Nieto'            from dual
 12                 )
 13    loop
 14      dbms_output.put_line(rpad(cur_r.bookid, 19, '.') ||
 15                           rpad(substr(cur_r.title, 1, 10), 18, '.') ||
 16                           rpad(cur_r.publisher, 22, '.') ||
 17                           cur_r.author
 18                          );
 19    end loop;
 20  end;
 21  /
BOOKID.............TITLE.............publisher.............Author
639163050..........10 years o........Prentice Hall.........Paul Dietel
330895717..........African fo........Prentice Hall.........Tem Nieto

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: This code does not work.Incorrect answer is still coming

Comment: Feel free to improve it because - from my point of view - it works.

Comment: I have uploaded the output my code fetches .Can i get suggetion what needs to be done.

Comment: If that's what YOUR code fetches, I suggest you use MY code.

Comment: On using your code here is the out put which has less dots:-BOOKID.............TITLE.............publisher.............Author
639163050..........10 years o........Prentice Hall.........Paul Dietel
330895717..........African fo........Prentice Hall.........Tem Nieto

Comment: Well, you'll either have it aligned (as my example shows), or you'll have any number of dots you want and misaligned output. Choose the one that suits you best.